# Check if String in JTextField is equal to VarChar in MySql Database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, arrays, database

I am trying to insert a new record into a database. Input the primary key of the record manually into a JTextField in my gui. I have a button labeled "Check" beside the JTextField. When I input the primary key into the textfield I want to click on the "Check" button to check if that primary key already exists in the database as I do not want a duplicate primary key.

For example if I have 6 records in the database. The primary keys are (a,b,c,d,e,f). If the check scans through the existing primary keys I want the check/scan to stop if it finds a match (one that is the same as the one in TextField). The problem is that is does not checking/scanning after its found a match. This is a problem as I want a little tick to appear beside the textfield only if there is no match. I am using a System.out.print to see if the results from the db equal the TextField. The System.out.print looks like

```
no match
no match 
no match 
no match 
 match   
no match

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "dublinzoo";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "root";

    //   String str = AnimalIdTf.getText().toString();
    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
        System.out.println("Database Connection Successful");

        // Set up a create statement
        java.sql.Statement stmn = conn.createStatement();

        // Set Up SQL
        String sql = "SELECT MAMMAL_ID FROM MAMMAL GROUP BY MAMMAL_ID";

        // Excute Query and send result set to rs
        ResultSet rs = stmn.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {

        // Retrieve by column name
        String MAMMAL_ID = rs.getString("MAMMAL_ID");

        String str = AnimalIdTf.getText().toString();

        if (MAMMAL_ID.equals(str)) {
            System.out.println("match");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Animal id already exists!" + "\n" + "Please enter a different id");
            AnimalIdTf.setText("");
        } else { 
            System.out.println(" no match");
            tickLabel.setVisible(true);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "id ok");
        }

        // Close the connection to the database
        conn.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: what is AnimalIdTf? where is it declared? what does str contain?

Comment: sorry i forgot to un-comment the line starting "String Str..." at the top. AnimalIdTf is the name of the textField  mentioned in the question. str contains the string value of whatever was entered into the AnimalIdTf textField

Comment: my advice would be to debug by printing out the values of str and then all the mamal ids - then you will know what's going on with the matching

Comment: Thank you ! i will do that and get back to you.

Comment: I would also suggest you switch `Statement` with `PreparedStatement` due to performance issues, You are also initializing the String Inside  the `while` use while loop to retrieve the values from the database and do the other Processing outside. Otherwise your code looks good.